# How to add touch event for custom uicontrol and controller?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uicontrol

I have a custom UIControl that has three subviews. Each of those subviews, I add a target:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped(clickedBtn:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Within that function `buttonTapped`, it does some special animations to do some transitions (It mimics the segmented control).

Now, within the ViewController that this custom UIControl exists in must know when it's touched. I created an `@IBAction` function that interacts with the touch events for the custom UIControl.

The problem is, that isn't possible (as far as I know). If I add a target touch event to the subviews, the parent touch events won't get called. To have the parent view called the `@IBAction` function, I must set all the subview's setUserInteractiveEnabled`to`true`. When I do that, the subview's touch event functions won't get called.

I need both touch event functions to be called. How can I do this? Or what's the best way to get around this?

Comment: Could you have the *entire* custom control be the `IBAction`, then in the `.touchUpInside` determine *which* subview was tapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use delegates, add a **protocol** in your UIControl that needs to be implemented in your ViewController.

This way you can detect if a button is clicked in your UIControl and invoke a specific function in your VC.

For Example:

```
//YourUIControl.Swift
protocol YourUIControlDelegate {
  func didTapFirstButton()
}

class YourUiControl : UIView { //I'm assuming you create your UIControl from UIView

  var delegate : YourUIControlDelegate?
  //other codes here
  .
  .
  .
  @IBAction func tapFirstButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
     if let d = self.delegate {
       d.didTapFirstButton()
     }
  }
}

//YourViewController.Swift
extension YourViewController : UIControlDelegate {
  func didTapFirstButton() {
     //handle first button tap here
  }
}
```

Comment: That worked! The only thing I had to add is in the `YourViewController`, in the `viewDidLoad`, you need to set the `YourUIControl` delegate to self.