# How to add touch event for custom UIControl and determine the touched item in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicontrol

I have created a custom UIControl. The UIControl contains multiple items like drawings and labels.

I want to be able to catch a tap on a label inside the ViewController.
Note that I add components inside the UIControl and that I am not using NIB/XIB files).

I am rather new at swift/iOS development. I am working in XCode 10.3 and swift 5. I did some Google searches which did not help me much. I also found this reference ([How to add touch event for custom uicontrol and controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145900/how-to-add-touch-event-for-custom-uicontrol-and-controller)), but I could not get that to work either.

I have added a minimal code example (based on a new project).

```
\\ File: SomeUI.swift
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class SomeUI: UIControl {

    private var componentsAdded = false
    private let labelOne = UILabel()
    private let labelTwo = UILabel()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if !componentsAdded {
            componentsAdded = true
            self.addSubview(labelOne)
            labelOne.text = "one"
            labelOne.sizeToFit()
            self.addSubview(labelTwo)
            labelTwo.text = "two"
            labelTwo.sizeToFit()
        }
        labelOne.center = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
        labelTwo.center = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 40)
    }
}
```

```
\\ File: ViewController.swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var someLabel: UILabel!

    func changeLabel() {
//        switch sender {
//        case labelOne: someLabel.text = "one"
//        case labelOne: someLabel.text = "two"
//        default: println("other")
//        }
    }
}
```

The Main.storyboard looks like this:

[image: Main.storyboard]

(https://postimg.cc/V5h7fdFf)

I would like to be able to implement the `changeLabel()` function in the ViewController.swift. Or implement something similar in functionality, such that it "catches" the tap on the UILabel and knows which UILabel was tapped.

Comment: I made a mistake in the second case option. It should read:

```//        case labelTwo: someLabel.text = "two"```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, all interactions with UILabel are disabled by default. To change it, set isUserInteractionEnabled to true.

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class SomeUI: UIControl {

    private var componentsAdded = false
    let labelOne = UILabel()
    private let labelTwo = UILabel()

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        labelOne.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        if !componentsAdded {
            componentsAdded = true
            self.addSubview(labelOne)
            labelOne.text = "one"
            labelOne.sizeToFit()
            self.addSubview(labelTwo)
            labelTwo.text = "two"
            labelTwo.sizeToFit()
        }
        labelOne.center = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
        labelTwo.center = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 40)
    }
}



\\ File: ViewController.swift
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

        @IBOutlet weak var someLabel: UILabel!
        @IBOutlet weak var sui: SomeUI!

        @IBAction func changeLabel(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
            let view = gestureRecognizer.view
            let loc = gestureRecognizer.location(in: view)
            let subview = sui.hitTest(loc, with: nil)

            switch subview {
            case sui.labelOne: print("1") someLabel.text = "label one tapped"
            case sui.labelTwo: print("2") someLabel.text = "label two tapped"
            default: print("0") someLabel.text = "TAPPIO?" }
        }
    }
```

In Storyboard add a Tap Gesture Recognizer and set its "Sent Actions" to "changeLabel", "Referencing outlet collections" to your custom SomeUI IBOutlet referenced here by "sui" property

> @IBOutlet weak var sui: SomeUI!